AmCharts Congressional map
I am trying to use a congressional map amCharts provides. However, I am unable to get it to load and I have had success with other charts and maps so I'm not sure what the problem is. The congressional map simply does not appear as you can see here. The other maps load but the congressional one is not present.
I am using WeWeb as my front-end and have formatted the JavaScript using https://weweb-embed.statechange.ai/. Below are the resources amCharts provides and that I install on the app load. (All available on the congressional map documentation)
  if(!window["scp-loading-4c8c5502-9b3b-4503-9eb3-00bdacdd6689"]) {
    window["scp-loading-4c8c5502-9b3b-4503-9eb3-00bdacdd6689"] = true;
    let doc;
    /* Adding script from https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js */
    doc = document.createElement('script');
    doc.src = 'https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js';
    document.body.appendChild(doc);
    /* Adding script from https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/map.js */
    doc = document.createElement('script');
    doc.src = 'https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/map.js';
    document.body.appendChild(doc);
    /* Adding script from https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/geodata/region/usa/congressional2022/usaCongressionalLow.js */
    doc = document.createElement('script');
    doc.src = 'https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/geodata/region/usa/congressional2022/usaCongressionalLow.js';
    document.body.appendChild(doc);
    /* Adding script from https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js */
    doc = document.createElement('script');
    doc.src = 'https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js';
    document.body.appendChild(doc);
  }

I then have the map appear in a container "chartdiv" using the following:
(please see first comment since this is capped at 30,000 characters.)
